# Angular forms adding and deleting inputs dynamicly

Tags: angular

So my problem is I want to add and remove answers input dynamically in the component with minimum 2 inputs .

but if I add a new one for example I have

1. input-1
2. input-2
3. input-3

and I delete input-1 or input-2
and then decide to add a new input. for example input-4
now I have
input-1
input-2
input-4
and after adding input-4 text in the input-2 disappears.

here is the code
here is youtube link if it will be helpful
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/USI6R7Bj4Kc)

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" 
style="display: flex; justify-content: center;flex-direction:column;align-items: center; padding: 100px 0;">
    <div *ngFor="let ans of task.questionAnswerModelList; let i = index">
      <input [(ngModel)]="ans.answerText" [required]="true" name="{{'answerText' + i}}" 
      style="height: 50px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <span style="background-color: red;" (click)="remove(i)">X</span>
      <span>{{ans.answerText}}</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" style="width: 100px; color: green;">Submit</button>
  </form>



  
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <button type="button" (click)="addAnswers()" 
style="background-color: aqua; color: white; border: none;padding: 1rem;">Add Answers</button>
</div>
```

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export interface QuestionAnswerModelInterface {
  answerText?: string;
  correct?: boolean;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class AppComponent{
  

  @ViewChild('form', {static: false}) public form!: NgForm;

  
  public task = {
    question: '',
    questionAnswerModelList: [
      {
        answerText: '',
      },
      {
        answerText: '',
      },
    ],
  };


  addAnswers(){
    this.task.questionAnswerModelList.push({
      answerText:''
    })
  }

  remove(i:number){
    if(this.task.questionAnswerModelList.length > 2 ){
      this.task.questionAnswerModelList.splice(i,1)
    }
  }

  submit(){
    console.log(this.form)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Angular Reactive Forms [Reactive Forms (angular.io)](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

In angular the typical way of accomplishing this task is to use the `ReactiveFormsModule` along with `FormArray`

---

#### Add ReactiveForms to your module

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      ReactiveFormsModule // import ReactiveForms in the module which hosts your Form
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

#### Create a FormGroup in your component [FormGroup (angular.io)](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

Each of your form inputs will be mapped to a control inside of a `FormGroup` on your controller class

*form-demo.component.ts*

```js
@Component()
export class FormDemoComponent implements OnInit {
  myFormGroup: FormGroup
  
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.myFormGroup = formBuilder.group({});
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

#### Add a FormArray to your FormGroup [FormArray (angular.io)](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

*form-demo.component.ts*

```js
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.myFormGroup = this.createForm();
}

createForm(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    rows: this.formBuilder.array([]) // creates a new FormArray
  });
}

// more easily access the dynamic form elements from template
get dynamicRows() {
  return this.myFormGroup.controls["rows"] as FormArray
}
```

#### Adding and removing elements from the FormArray

A FormArray holds a collection of FormGroups. Each FormGroup holds the controls for our input elements. In this example, I will add two inputs, one number input and one text input.

*form-demo.component.ts*

```js
  addFormRow() {
    this.dynamicRows.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      text: this.formBuilder.control(''),
      number: this.formBuilder.control(0)
    }))
  }

  removeFormRow(idx: number) {
    this.dynamicRows.removeAt(idx);
  }
```

Now we are able to add and remove FormGroups to the FormArray. If we want to reset the entire Form we simply have to call createForm

#### The Template

*form-demo.component.html*

```html
<button (click)="addFormRow()">Add Row</button>
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <ng-container formArrayName="rows">
    <div *ngFor="let control of dynamicRows.controls; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="text" formControlName="text">
      <input type="number" formControlName="number">
      <button (click)="removeFormRow(i)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qpybpy?file=src/app/form-demo/form-demo.component.ts)

Comment: thanks a lot.  it works now. Do you have any idea why it did not work with TD forms?